# Lamda function for counting items shows error

Tags: excel, lambda, countif

I have the below data.  I'm working on a Lamda function that can match positive numbers with corresponding negative numbers.

I'm working on them step by step.  However I find it strange that my Lamda1 is producing results and Lamda2 is showing up error.  When all Lamda2 has is an extended version of Lamda1.

Lambda 1 :

=LAMBDA(SearchRng, LET(SKey, COUNTIF(SearchRng,INDEX(SearchRng,SEQUENCE(ROWS(SearchRng)))), TRng, (SearchRng&SKey)*1, TRng))(B4:B11)

Lambda 2 :

=LAMBDA(SearchRng, LET(SKey, COUNTIF(SearchRng,INDEX(SearchRng,SEQUENCE(ROWS(SearchRng)))), TRng, (SearchRng&SKey)*1, **T1Rng, COUNTIF(TRng, INDEX(TRng, SEQUENCE(ROWS(TRng)))),** T1Rng))(B4:B11)

Why I think this is happening, is because SearchRng is considered as a Range, but TRng is considered as an Array.  If so, is there a way convert Array to Range.

[image]